# What's the best way to debug vagrant up hanging at "Setting the name of the VM: ..."

Tags: vagrant

I destroyed my CoreOS vagrant box, then tried to re-up but it's hanging at:

```
==> core-01: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> core-01: Checking if box 'coreos-alpha' is up to date...
==> core-01: Setting the name of the VM: coreos-vagrant_core-01_1447605695441_10076
```

In my VirtualBox graphical user interface, coreos-vagrant_core-01_1447605695441_10076 is shown as being Powered Off.

And then, nothing happens.

My question is: how best to debug this? How can I get more information about what is going on and where it's hanging?

Answer (score 1):

`vagrant up --debug` will give you logging info from the VM

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Windows.

The suggestion (solution) based on my experience:

**If you have updated/modified your puphpet *config.yaml* file recently:**

- If recenlty downloaded from puphpet.com make sure you have compatible vagrant version, currently: Minimum required Vagrant version is ***1.7.4***
- Try changing your *sync_type:* to ***default*** *(recommended for win is SMB, but for me personally this would cause to hang, until changed to default)*

And last but not least, try running (up) with debug option, like so:

```
    vagrant up --debug
```

P.S. Notice the double -- *dash*